# Polymer paper-card failed to construct CustomElement

Tags: polymer

I've got an application that seems to work fine when I put all my elements inside a `<dom-bind>` element. When I remove that `dom-bind` (no longer needed), most of the elements carry on working, but paper-card stops and throws an error:

> "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'CustomElement': The result must not have attributes"

The error is thrown from `polymer/lib/legacy/lib/class.html` if that helps. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error, and find out angular create an empty element (), then bind stuffs to it.

This fail according to spec:

> 4.13.2 Requirements for custom element constructors
>
> The element must not gain any attributes or children

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-element-conformance

I fix my problem by assigning in connectedCallback()